# Getting metrics exception with CassandraConfig using Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I'm getting the below exception during the application startup. `@EnableCassandraRepositories` is part of the `Application` class. 
I'm using spring-data-cassandra. 
I tried excluding metrics from different dependencies but none of them worked.

Below is the error and the config code and the dependencies that I used.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/lte/assessmentanalytics/config/CassandraConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/codahale/metrics/Metric
```

CassandraConfig

```
    @Configuration
    public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {
        @Value("${cassandra.contactpoints}")
        private String contactPoints;
        @Value("${cassandra.port}")
        private int port;
        @Value("${cassandra.keyspace}")
        private String keySpace;
        @Value("${cassandra.basePackages}")
        private String basePackages;

        @Autowired
        private Environment environment;

        @Override
        protected String getKeyspaceName() {
            return keySpace;
        }

        @Override
        @Bean
        public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
            final CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
            cluster.setContactPoints(contactPoints);
            cluster.setPort(port);
            return cluster;
        }

        @Override
        @Bean
        public CassandraMappingContext cassandraMapping() throws ClassNotFoundException {
            return new BasicCassandraMappingContext();
        }
    }
```

Dependencies

```
 <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
                            <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
                <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
                        <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
                <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
            </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be missing the codahale metrics. Try adding this to your pom:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.codahale.metrics</groupId>
     <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```